# O Angular 2 substitui jQuery e AJAX?

Tags: jquery, angular

Com a utilização do Angular 2, ainda é necessário ainda a utilização do jQuery e AJAX ou o Angular faz a substituição 100% dessas 2 tecnologias?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O Angular faz substituição a 100%. É possível misturar se estiveres dependente de código antigo. Mas a ideia é deixar o jQuery para trás...

Se nunca soubesses que jQuery existia era quase melhor para começar uma app em Angular, Vue ou React :)

O conceito desta nova geração de aplicações reactivas é não mexer no DOM como antigamente. A aplicação toma conta do DOM e o paradigma de programação deve ser mais funcional/reactivo. Quando algo no estado (state) da aplicação mudar isso deve refletir-se no DOM. E não como antigamente: usar jQuery para implementar no DOM o que está no state. Ou ainda pior, ir ler no DOM dados para processamento da aplicação.

Há obviamente coisas em que o jQuery ainda pode ser útil. Ajax é uma delas. Mas é preferível nesse caso usar bibliotecas mais especializadas para funcionalidades que são necessárias. O Angular tem o `$http`, o React e o Vue.js são agnósticos, ou seja podes usar o que quiseres. Caso necessário, [o Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) é uma boa alternativa.

Comment: Boa resposta, só acho que deveria citar o "Ajax" que o AP fala.

Comment: @LINQ bem visto, juntei. Obrigado.

Comment: No caso esse React substitui o Angular? ou eles andam em conjunto?

Comment: @NicolaBogar React, Vue e Angular são as 3 bibliotecas mais populares nesta nova geração de bibliotecas "reactivas".

Comment: Entendi, então eu deveria apenas me atentar a aprender 1 tecnologia, não teria necessidade de aprender todas, certo ?

Comment: @NicolaBogar exato. Todas são JavaScript, por isso saber JavaScript é o mais importante, e podes fazer isso em paralelo com uma dessas bibliotecas claro.

Comment: Perfeito @Sergio, você sabe onde posso achar alguma documentação do angular com o ASP.NET MVC, procurei pela internet e vi que é bem escasso esse tópico, só consegui achar com ASP.NET CORE

Comment: @NicolaBogar na verdade não. O mundo ASP.NET é-me completamente alheio :) Eu estou mais em casa com Node.js e PHP... Mas se tiveres alguma duvida específica há boa gente aqui que quer ajudar.

Comment: @Sergio, muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos amigo..

Comment: @NicolaBogar de nada!

Comment: E o MooTools? :)

Comment: @Maniero o MooTools é bem mais poderoso que jQuery, por isso consegue fazer o que o Angular faz ou o Vue com mais qualidade. Mas é de outra geração e na prática abandonado, infelizmente.