# WebPack + NodeJS import bootstrap + jquery

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap, vue.js, webpack

Olá pessoal da Stackoverflow,

Estou com um projeto VueJS já com Webpack. E fui importar as bibliotecas JQuery e Bootstrap. Fui no meu node e usei os comandos

```
npm install jquery --save-dev
npm install bootstrap --save-dev
```

Ok, fui na minha página main **Main.vue**

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Fui em um **Template Filho** ( *Footer.vue* ) e testei um alert

```
$('document').ready(function(){ alert('JQuery Worked!') });
```

**Funcionou** perfeitamente. Tentei então importar no mesmo lugar o **Bootstrap** após o **Jquery**:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
import 'boostrap'
```

e o console me retorna: **Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery**

Porque o bootstrap não encontra o Jquery sendo que testei o Jquery antes de importar o bootstrap?

Obrigado!

Comment: Não uses jQuery e Vue. Se queres usar Vue + Bootstrap podes usar o https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/

Comment: Hmm porque não posso usar jquery e bootstrap com o vuejs?

Comment: Podes, mas não deves, são maneiras de programar e gerir o estado da aplicação muito diferentes. E se é um projeto novo então é mesmo hora de deixar o jQuery. Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/234059/129

Comment: Então, é que não é um projeto novo. Estou migrando um projeto já existente para o VueJS. E neste projeto eu uso muito o JQuery Datatable... Fica ruim de eu abandonar o jquery assim

Comment: Compreendo. Tenta adaptar para vue datatables, há alguns para escolher. Se tem mesmo que ser, junta o jQuery, mas se não for muito esforço era melhor tirar.

Comment: Entendi... De qualquer forma, o erro dos imports vai continuar me perseguindo ou tem alguma maneira de arrumar?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Junta o plugin do jQuery no webpack para ele estar disponivel na aplicação:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
       })
    ]
};
```

E quando instalas o jQuery e bootsrap deves ter a flag `--save` e não `--save-dev` pois são dependências de produção.

Comment: Abri meu Webpack.config e nele não tem plugins, mas tem isso aqui: "  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([ <-  CODE  -> ]) . Tentei colocar dentro do 'Code', compilei de novo e o erro continua =/

Comment: @Jackson tens esse projeto online? tipo no github ou numa pasta zipada?

Comment: Consegui aqui, eu coloquei como último parâmetro do module.exports e funcionou! Obrigado =)