# jQuery com Angular e React

Tags: jquery, angular, react

Comecei a estudar recentemente Angular e React e tenho uma dúvida para os que são experientes com essas tecnologias. Utilizá-las juntamente com jQuery é inadequado?

Comment: Você que tem que se perguntar porque quer fazer isto

Comment: Apesar de ser possível integrá-los, não é recomendável, visto que o *react* não terá "conhecimento" das alterações feitas no DOM pelo *jQuery*.

Comment: Conforme os colegas acima responderam, é inadequeado. Não tem porque fazer assim, é adicionar complexidade ao invés de remover.

Comment: Vou falar pelo que eu conheco. O React utiliza uma "versão virtual" do DOM. Essa versão virutal do DOM nada mais é que um "conjunto de dados" do DOM e não o DOM em si. A ideia por trás disso é que o DOM em si carrega muitos dados e portanto pode levar a problemas de performance/manutenção em aplicações com um tamanho grande. A abordagem do DOM virtual abstrai as partes relevantes e realiza somente as atualizações necessárias. Portanto não faz sentido usar jQuery junto com React, até porque isso trará sérios problemas de performance a sua aplicação React.

Comment: Para terminar deixo essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/234061/76995) do Sergio! Pode ser bem útil e vai esclarecer alguns pontos para você!

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos pelas respostas! Sou web designer, tenho grande conhecimento em jQuery para criar componentes e animações e recentemente comecei estudar Angular e React, pensei em íntegra los com jQuery para aproveitar o conhecimento que tenho na biblioteca. Os componentes em React e Angular tem todos a mesma cara, na minha opinião achei complicado customiza los.