# Qual a vantagem de usar ANGULAR sobre JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, angular

Sei que ambos são diferentes.
Sei que Angular eh um Framework e o Jquery uma LIB.

Mas pergunto a os profissionais que lidam com ambos, qual eh a vantagem, o que consigo fazer no ANGULAR que nao consigo fazer com JQUERY e recebendo os dados do Back? Li e reli alguns artigos e nao consegui me convencer do Angular, fiz um mini curso recente de ANGULAR e vi a qtde de coisas q tem q digitar, talvez por nao estar acostumado ao ANGULAR vejo ele como um bicho de sete cabeças, onde o jQUERY faz tudo que preciso e nao tenho encontrado enroscos.

Entao, colegas o que ganho com ANGULAR ou outro Framework Javascript que nao consiga fazer com JQUERY ? 
Pois me deparei com uma situacao num curso de LARAVEL que vi o cara correndo atras do rabo ensinando a usar ANGULAR o que me levou a fazer o curso pra me situar, e vi que poderia fazer aquilo que ele passou usando Jquery com Ajax sem maiores dificuldades.

Comment: Outra relacionada: [O Angular 2 substitui jQuery e AJAX?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/234059/5878)

Answer (score 2):

A principal motivação para se utilizar frameworks como Angular, React e Vue, é a consistência dos dados nas single-page application.

JQuery é uma solução de compatibilidade entre diversos navegadores, que também lhe trás vários métodos para manipulação de objetos e DOM, o que torna seu trabalho mais prático.

Angular não foi feito exatamente para tornar seu trabalho mais prático, mas sim para torna-lo mais seguro e escalável. Um exemplo simples: imagine que você tem vários widgets/componentes e queira traze-los todos para a mesma página. Se eles não foram criados com a interação em mente, é possível que você tenha vários problemas: variáveis globais se sobrescrevendo, elementos com o mesmo id, queries de um componente buscando acidentalmente elementos de outro componente.

O Angular busca solucionar esse problema criando escopos isolados para cada componente, e mudando a forma com a qual você manipula o DOM, reduzindo risco de gerar interações inesperadas.